# Titanium Appcelerator longjohn.js:185 error

Tags: android, node.js, titanium, npm

When I am trying to run my Android application using Titanium Studio, I got error like this..

```
[INFO] : Making sure the adb server is running
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
C:\Users\Ganeshk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\longjohn\dist\longjohn.js:185
    throw e;
          ^
patchedLog [as log] (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\cli\commands\build.js:299:22),target.(anonymous function) [as error] (C:\Users\Ganeshk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\common.js:45:21),C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\cli\hooks\run.js:399:13,C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:232:13,C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:136:21,C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:229:17,C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:556:34,C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\adb.js:455:4,ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\node_modules\node-appc\lib\subprocess.js:60:3)
```

I am using:

- OS: Windows 8,
- npm: 2.7.4,
- Titanium: 3.4.2

Comment: It is hard to help if we can not see what is inside `longjohn.js` (mainly around the line 185). You didn't catch an exception there...

Answer (score 0):

## Option-1:

Confirm that you have 0.10.X version of node.js

## Option-2

Can you try the following change. This involves modifying a file, so would request you to keep a backup of the file.

Go to the following folder:
C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\

Open the file windows.js and edit the following line (should be near the end)

```
if (!selectedVisualStudio) return next();
```

and change it to:

```
return next();
```

Let us know if either of this two approach worked for you. For me, option-2 worked in one of our windows machine.